# Vertically centered nested DIVs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is there a way to vertically center *n* nested divs in pure CSS?

Consider the unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products & Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like the list to appear horizontally on a responsive web site. So for that I'd use the table layout, applying display:table to the `<ul>` and display:table-cell to the `<li>` elements.

But inside these `<li>` elements, I'd also like the  elements to be vertically centered. This is important because in a responsive design, we aren't aware of when the text in the `<a>` elements will flow onto two lines or be contained in one. E.g. The Home link above would only ever occupy one line, whereas the Products & Services link would occupy two at smaller widths.

Now, we can't use the table trick here because here the parent element `<li>` has display:table-cell, and not display:table.

Is there a way to do this:

1. ***without*** changing the HTML structure above? This is often the default structuring for menus in CMSs like WordPress and sometimes we don't have the option to change it;
2. in pure CSS, without the help of jQuery; and
3. to work in all modern browsers?

(Please don't suggest using a non-table layout for the `<li>` elements. The above example is just that: an example; and the question still remains: can we vertically center immediately nested divs?)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply add `vertical-align:middle;` to the `li` elements with `display:table-cell;` set.

[Vertical Align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.

Comment: Is element with `display:table-cell;` have to parent with `display:table`?

Comment: When I mention using the table trick above it already implies, of course, using vertical-align:middle. The question still remains however. Because consider the case where we have a `<span>` tag inside the `<a>` tag. How do we vertically center that?

Comment: Sergey: please read the last line of my question: (Please don't suggest using a non-table layout for the `<li>` elements. The above example is just that: an example; and the question still remains: can we vertically center immediately nested divs?)

Comment: @Seano why not then do: `li *{vertical-align:middle}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
li {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/Xqz7Z/1/)

Comment: When I mention using the table trick above it already implies, of course, using vertical-align:middle. The question still remains.

Comment: @Seano The question then should be, "I have `vertical-align:middle;` but it isn't working". I've updated my answer with a working example. Works in all browsers I've tried it on (IE9 to IE11, Chrome, Firefox). [Even works with divs](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqz7Z/2/)